# Unexpected behavior with dynamic List

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

The following throws a runtime exception on the last line:

```
dynamic dynamicCollection = new List<ExpandoObject>();

dynamic itemOne = new ExpandoObject();
itemOne.Name = "itemOne";
dynamicCollection.Add(itemOne);

dynamic itemTwo = new ExpandoObject();
itemTwo.Name = "itemTwo";
dynamicCollection.Add(itemTwo);

var firstItem = dynamicCollection.First();
```

'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>' does not contain a definition for 'First'

What's happening here? This looks completely legal. It's clearly being recognized as a `List<ExpandoObject>`, and a generic collection should not care about the value of `T`.. right?

Comment: Is it a Compile time error? if so try to include using System.Linq namespace

Comment: ExtensionMethods are resolved (at compile time) to static methods that take the source as the first argument. Dynamic at runtime. If you call the static method directly and supply your dynamic list as the first argument it could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) method is an [extention method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) located in `System.Linq.Enumerable` rather than `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. This means that a `dyanmic` object, which looks up *members* at runtime, cannot resolve what `.First()` means because `List<T>` does, as said, not contain that method. The big issue here is that it's looking for a member, and doesn't check for Extension Methods when it goes to resolve.

Syntactically, you can say `List<T>.First()` because it's syntactic sugar. You can also refer to the full method, and you'll have to get this code to work, because `dynamic` objects don't check for extension methods.

```
Enumerable.First(dyanmicCollection);
```

At compile time, this is what extension methods effectively expand to anyway, so you're basically bypassing the sugar,

Comment: Did you try my example? I think you're missing the point of my question. I'm not having an issue with First() in general.

Comment: My apologies! I see the answer now, updating accordingly

Comment: Yep, this makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `dynamicCollection` to be `dynamic`? If not, you can use concrete type for the list itself:

```
var dynamicCollection = new List<ExpandoObject>();
...
dynamic firstItem = dynamicCollection.First();
Console.WriteLine(firstItem.Name);
```

and then `dynamicCollection.First()` will be resolved as an extension method call as you expect.
Return type of this method is `ExpandoObject`, so you also should cast it to `dynamic` to access `Name` property.

Comment: Yes I do. The example is only a simple representation of the problem. Good point though, maybe can help someone else.